# flexible join condition in Spark (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join

I want to have a flexible join condition that can be passed for example as a string (or any other suggestion?). For instance, in the following statement the FLEXIBLE_CONDITION expression can change in different runs.

```
val df3 = df1.join(df2, FLEXIBLE_CONDITION, "fullouter")
```

Few examples:

```
 (1) df1(s"query") === df2 (s"query_df2") 
 (2) df1(s"id") === df2(s"id_df2") && df1(s"item") === df2(s"item_df2")
 (3) Or combination of (1) and (2) or any other condition
```

It needs to be noted that the column names that join will be done based on them are different. For example, in (1), in df1 the column name is query and in df2 it is query_df2 and so on.

The FLEXIBLE_CONDITION shouldn't be hardcoded but can be an input and may change frequently. Or can be automated based on a set of input (e.g. column names).

Answer (score 0):

You can provide expression, which should be using in join

signature for this

```
def join(right: Dataset[_], joinExprs: Column): DataFrame
```

For example,

```
val df1 = Seq(
    ("a1", "b1"),
    ("a2", "b2")
).toDF("a", "b")

val df2 = Seq(
    ("b1", "a1"),
    ("b2", "a2")
).toDF("b1", "a1")

df1.show
df2.show
```

output

```
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
| a1| b1|
| a2| b2|
+---+---+

+---+---+
| b1| a1|
+---+---+
| b1| a1|
| b2| a2|
+---+---+
```

you can build any expression you want ant provide it to join

```
val expression = df1("a") === df2("a1")
val result = df1 join (df2, expression)

result.show
```

output

```
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b| b1| a1|
+---+---+---+---+
| a1| b1| b1| a1|
| a2| b2| b2| a2|
+---+---+---+---+
```

UPD:

You can use `createOrReplaceTempView`
For example

```
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")

val res = spark.sql("select * from df1 inner join df2 on df1.a == df2.a1")
res.show
```

output

```
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b| b1| a1|
+---+---+---+---+
| a1| b1| b1| a1|
| a2| b2| b2| a2|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Result will be the same and you can provide sql query as string

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Using expression here again needs hard coding the condition. The condition can be an input for example, a string or any other suggestion?

Comment: @Xan i updated my solution, maybe it is what you needed

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This is what I was looking for:

```
 val first :  String = unique_attrs(0)
 var expression : org.apache.spark.sql.Column = df1(first) === df2_r(s"$first" + "_df2")
 for (i <- 1 to unique_attrs.length - 1) {
   val attr : String = unique_attrs(1)
   expression = expression && df1(attr) === df2_r(s"$attr" + "_df2")
 }

 val df3 = df1.join(df2_r, expression, "fullouter")
```

The list of attribute is given as an input (unique_attrs) to the method.